# Make a "typedef" be final (or simulate it)

Tags: c++, c++14, alias, typedef, final

Is it possible to mark an alias of a `type` as `final` (i.e. can't be re-defined in derived class)?

```
#include <iostream>
class B{
    public: using type=std::string;
};
class D : public B{
    public: using type=int;     //<--- [1] I want a compile error here.
};
int main(){
    typename D::type str="abc"; //<--- [2] This line is actually correct.
}
```

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final, it is for function only.
  Is there a workaround?

It would be useful as a coder fool-proof in some cases.

Comment: You can't override type aliases in the first place, so `final` would be rather misleading.

Comment: @chris  Thank, I agree.   I probably also use a wrong word .... still don't know a correct one.

Comment: When you say _//<--- [2] This line is actually correct_, you mean that is what YOU want. Right? The `str` var should be `int` type since you redefined it.

Comment: @realharry Yes, I want it to be correct.  In other words, I wish the compiler to say "[1] is wrong" rather than "[2] is wrong".

Comment: Your'e not "overriding" it. `B::type` is still `std::string`. `D::type` is an `int`. The qualification matters.

Comment: As for "useful as a coder fool-proof " - get better coders

Comment: I agree. You seem to think there is some kind of inheritance/polymorphism in "using type", but that is not really correct. The "class B" and "class D" in your example are merely namespaces.

Comment: @StoryTeller  Agree, but the same coder can probably do better with better tool-set.

Comment: @realharry I never thought about it that way (namespace), thank.

Comment: The same coder should stick to "safe" languages instead if this sort of thing is a problem inducer.

Comment: In any case, this should be possible with metaclasses (or basic reflection if applied differently), but I don't see much of a way to enforce it currently.

Comment: What you are really looking for is a general anti - name-hiding feature, I think. Personally, I like scope name hiding, but I know many others don't. Personally, I would like a no-function scoped name-hide, so I can say "This block must/can not access this member", and will occasionally define dummy enums for this purpose.

Comment: @Gem Taylor Is it possible to extend/adapt dummy-enums to work for type?

Comment: They will hide any name, but they have the opposite effect to what you want, as they make the name and the thing it refers to  unavailable to the code. Also, it is still possible to assign the name again at a deeper nesting.
I will throw up a simple example as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot.

Trait based types could do it, but the machinery is ugly.

Define a distributed type map maybe via an adl based tag function map.

```
template<class T>struct tag_t{constexpr tag_t(){} using type=T;};
template<class T>constexpr tag_t<T> tag{};

namespace trait {
  template<class T>
  constexpr void type_tag( tag_t<T> ){}
  template<class T>
  using type=typename decltype( type_tag( tag<T> ) )::type;
}

// non-final alias
struct A{
  friend constexpr tag_t<int> type_tag(tag_t<A>){return {};}
};
// non-final alias
struct A{
  friend constexpr tag_t<char> type_tag(tag_t<A>){return {};}
};
// final alias
struct B{
  template<class T, std::enable_if_t< std::is_base_of<B,T>{}, bool> =true>
  friend constexpr tag_t<std::string> type_tag(tag_t<T>){return {};}
};
```

now overriding `A`'s `type_tag` works with `trait::type<>` but if you try the same with `B` you'll get a long incomprehensible error.

This is a bad plan.

Metaclasses will probably let you do something like this as well.

In general, both of these require writing a new sublanguage of C++ to enforce a constraint C++ does not enforce.  Possible, but ill-advised unless you have an extemely good reason.

Comment: It is funny that you answered a lot of questions here with tag-magic.   I am also satisfied that you dare to answer this one with a big no.  Thank.

Answer (score 1):

Tangential answer on how we could use enums or other dummies to usefully hide a type.

```
/*
 * Imagine everybody uses managed strings in our project throughout,
 * so everyone expects to be able to declare and print strings everywhere,
 * especially for debugging...
 */
typedef OurInternalMangedStrings string;
/***/

void InternalStringManager::ReallyDoingNastyInternalStuff()
{
    // Within this code casually using managed strings 
    // to format error messages, etc, 
    // would be fatal as it will cause nasty recursion.
    enum DoNotUseStrings_DeadlockDanger { string, OurInternalMangedStrings };
    printError(string ("I had an error here and I don't know why - code ") << errCode);

}
```

This will produce an error which will hopefully mention both string and DoNotUseStrings_DeadlockDanger, giving the clue.

But it is of limited use for types as while it stops the author from using the word "string", it doesn't stop the code from automatically performing conversion, or using objects of that type that already exist, eg the following will pass without comment if the constructor is not explicit:

```
printError("I had an error here and I don't know why at all!");
```

For data values I find it is more useful:

```
void MyManager::Setup()
{
    {    SomeFeature newPimple = new Somefeature;
         enum DoNotUseMember {someFeature};

         /** set up newPimple using other member data and parameters 
             when it is ready I will assign it to the member variable "someFeature"
          **/
         /** any accidental use of a someFeature member will produce error message **/
         // Ready to install the new pimpl as the visible feature
         MUTEX_RAII(access_feature); // ... Or whatever might be needed
         /* can still access someFeature by being explicit */
         delete this->someFeature;
         this->someFeature = newPimpl;
    }
    /** other setup code that uses the new feature **/
}
```

Personally, I would call the new instance someFeature and get the hiding behaviour for free, but many find the name reuse hard to read.

Another way I use this technique is in refactoring. I have a method that happily uses member values to control its behaviour, and then an enhancement is needed where one of the control values must be controlled externally. To implement this, the original no-argument method becomes a shim, calling a new method with the member as the argument.

But how to ensure the new method doesn't accidentally use the member instead of the argument? Personally, I'd make the argument mask the member, but we are again limited by the comprehension of others.

Comment: Thank.  It is useful and creative.